# Get a return value from C++ program to a Python script using subprocess

Tags: python, c++, subprocess, return-value

I am using `subprocess.Popen()` in a Python script to run an executable of C++ program. I need to return a value from the C++ program which can be used in the Python script.

I have lots of `printf` statements in the C++ program, so I can't use `PIPE` and get the output.

Can I return a single value which is received by the script?

Answer (score 0):

Check the `returncode` attribute of the object returned by `Popen`.

Note that it is only filled if you have called `poll()` or `wait()` first on the `Popen` object.

Comment: If I use return-code of Popen it gives me exit code 0 since executable(of cpp file) ran fine. But I want to return something different in cpp file according to it which I can receive in script.

Comment: @ShivamKumar Why cannot you return something different than `0`? If you don't want to change the exit code, you may be able to use `stderr` instead of `stdout`. Otherwise, you can use any means of inter-process communication, like a pipe.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is solved. Basically python script subprocess can recieve exit code. cpp file can return that code from int main() which can be used as exit code of the prog in python script.